# Global request/response interceptor in express

Tags: node.js, express

I understand express middlewares. They are like tunnels between request to reponse.
`req -> t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> res`
All middlewares accpets three arguments `req, res, next`. `next()` is what passes execution to next tunnel.
Error middlewares are a bit different as they accept four arguments `err, req, res, next`.
So, if an error occurs in any tunnel, it will skip rest of them and pass the handle to next `error middleware`
I need to make an global interceptor using middlewares.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

//here I can create a middleware for intercepting the request - which is fine
app.use('*', async function(req, res, next) {
  // access req.body here
  next();
});

// route handlers
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  // do stuff
  return res.status(200).send({..});
});

// error handler
app.use(async function(err, req, res) {
  // log error
  return res.status(500).send({...});
});
```

As you can see, I am not passing `next` to route handler, It is being passed by a library to the next error handler itself if any error occurs in the route handler.
This is what I tried, but getting error.

```
// route handlers
app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  // do stuff
  res.status(200).send({..});
  next();
});

// error handler
app.use(async function(err, req, res) {
 if(!error)
     //modify res.body
  // log error
  return res.status(500).send({...});
});
```

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

I know this error occurs if I am trying to send response again.
How can I access response body and modify it before it gets sent?

Comment: why do you have `next()` in the '/' route as well? if you want to handle errors you should do `next(err)` is a catch clause or something of that sort and not send a 200 response like you are doing.

Comment: @Odinn The idea is to pass the  handler to the next middleware where I would access response body. But I am not clear how.

Comment: OK so you want to modify the response body via middleware and the return the response right? I think if you do next before res.send that would be a good start assuming that you are not doing any res.send in the middleware... you will probably need to add req.context or something of that sort so that the data you want is passed to the middleware and then use that req.context to build the body in the response maybe... something of that sort if it makes sense

Comment: @Odinn for `next(err)` _Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error_ https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: That's fine but i'm talking about the code you showed us in the '/' route where you are doing 'next()' after res.send

Answer (score 2):

Create a modifyResponse.js as a middleware

```
const mung = require('express-mung');
const encryptdecryptfunctionsv2 = require('../../app/middleware/encryptdecryptv2');

async function redact(body, req, res) {
   let response = await encryptdecryptfunctionsv2.responseEncrypt(body);
   return { response };
}

module.exports = mung.jsonAsync(redact);
```

Then use in server.js

```
app.use(require('./app/service/modifyResponse.js'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, only option I have here is not to send response from handler itself but to pass it to another middleware.

```
// route handlers
app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  // do stuff
const locals = {
  status: 200,
   data: data,
   message: message,
}
  res.locals = locals;
  next();
});

// modify locals in  another middleware
app.use( async function(req, res) {
 // access and modify res.locals
return res.status(res.locals.status).send({ 
    message: res.locals.message,
    data: res.locals.data, 
});
```

Anyone has better option, please do suggest.